# Arraylist in fragments always returning size 0

Tags: android, arraylist, fragment

Im using a fragment to display datas in sqlite database in a recyclerview. I set up a textView where in if arraylist.size()==0 it will display an message and if not it will not. The problem is the arraylist.size() is always returning zero even though there is data in the database.

In adding data to database I use this

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView errorWeight = (TextView)weight.getSelectedView();
            TextView errorPer = (TextView)per.getSelectedView();
            TextView errorRepeat = (TextView)repeat.getSelectedView();

            if (name_food.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                name_food.setError("Please add a title to the task");
            }
            else if (date.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                date.setError("Set date to start");
            }
            else if (time.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                time.setError("Set time to start");
            }
            else if (quantity.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                quantity.setError("Set amount of food");
            }
            else if (weight.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Weight")) {
                errorWeight.setError("Set weight of food");
            }
            else if (per.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Per")) {
                errorPer.setError("Set Per meal or per day");
            }
            else if (repeat.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Repeat Task after")) {
                errorRepeat.setError("Set task repetition");
            }
            else
            {
                name_food.setError(null);
                date.setError(null);
                time.setError(null);
                quantity.setError(null);
                errorWeight.setError(null);
                errorPer.setError(null);
                errorRepeat.setError(null);
                arrayLists=new ArrayList<>();
                food_model item=new food_model();
                db=new food_database(add_food.this);
                adapter=new foodRecyclerAdapter(add_food.this,arrayLists);
                item.setPet_id(Integer.valueOf(petid.getText().toString()));
                item.setPet_name(name_pet.getText().toString());
                item.setType_food(name_food.getText().toString());
                item.setDate(date.getText().toString());
                item.setTime(time.getText().toString());
                item.setQuantity(quantity.getText().toString());
                item.setFood_weight(weight.getSelectedItem().toString());
                item.setMeal(per.getSelectedItem().toString());
                item.setNote(note.getText().toString());
                item.setSched(repeat.getSelectedItem().toString());
                boolean addfood=db.insertDataTofood(item);
                if(addfood)
                {
                    adapter.addItem(item);
                    Toast.makeText(add_food.this,"Task has been added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(add_food.this,"Item added"+arrayLists.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(add_food.this,foodActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    intent.putExtra("id",id);
                    intent.putExtra("breed",breed);
                    intent.putExtra("type",type);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(add_food.this,"Task not added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Then in the Recyclerview adapter i use this method to add data into the arraylist

```
 public void addItem(food_model item) {
    foodarraylist.add(0, item);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Then in fragments

```
    public class food_sched extends Fragment {
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView reminder,subreminder;
Context context;
ArrayList<food_model> model;
Cursor c;
foodRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    String name,id,type,breed;
    public food_sched() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model=new ArrayList<>();
        Intent taker=getActivity().getIntent();
        name=taker.getStringExtra("name");
        id=taker.getStringExtra("id");
        type=taker.getStringExtra("type");
        breed=taker.getStringExtra("breed");
        context=getActivity();
        if(model.size()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"size is "+model.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"size is "+model.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_food_sched, container, false);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_recyclerview);
        reminder=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_reminder);
        subreminder=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_reminder_sub);
        floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.add_food);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        loadfoodDB(context);
        setFoodAlarms(context);
        updateviews(context);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),add_food.class);
            intent.putExtra("petname",name);
            intent.putExtra("petid",id);
                intent.putExtra("petbreed",breed);
                intent.putExtra("pettype",type);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        adapter.updateDataOnNotification(model);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;

    }
```

And this method to load datas from database

```
public void loadfoodDB(Context context)
{
    food_database db=new food_database(context);
    food_db_retrieve foodDbRetrieve=new food_db_retrieve(context);
    foodDbRetrieve.openDB();
    model=new ArrayList<>();
    int newid=Integer.valueOf(id);

    c = db.queryData("select * from food_schedule WHERE pet_id ='"+newid+"' ORDER BY food_ID DESC");

    try {
        if(c != null)
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    food_model items=new food_model();
                    items.setFood_id(c.getInt(0));
                    items.setPet_id(c.getInt(1));
                    items.setPet_name(c.getString(2));
                    items.setType_food(c.getString(3));
                    items.setDate(c.getString(4));
                    items.setTime(c.getString(5));
                    items.setQuantity(c.getString(6));
                    items.setFood_weight(c.getString(7));
                    items.setMeal(c.getString(8));
                    items.setNote(c.getString(9));
                    items.setSched(c.getString(10));
                    model.add(items);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter = new foodRecyclerAdapter(context,model);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    foodDbRetrieve.closeDB();
}
```

Can you tell me why is it returning 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are showing toast just after the ArrayList created.

Move the Toast to `onCreateView()` or load data in `onCreate()`

Because `onCreateView()` called after the `onCreate()`

Your `onCreateView()` should be something like this.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_food_sched, container, false);

        -------------------
        -------------------
        loadfoodDB(context);


      if(model.size()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"size is "+model.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"size is "+model.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

         ------------------------
         ------------------------

        return view;

    }
```